# Laravel Inner join to get User Email Address and send Email

Tags: php, laravel, inner-join, laravel-mail

I want to send an email to the person who I received a package for, but the shipment table only has the user id, and i want to send a email to the person i add a shipment for. How can i inner join on the shipment table and the user table to get email address and send the email.

```
 // add shipment to DB
      $newShipment =  Shipment:: create([
            'user_id' => $request->mailBoxNo,
            'vendor'=> $request->vendor,
            'weight'=> $request->weight,
            'transitStatus'=> '1',
            'isInvoiceReady'=>'0',
            'trackingNumber'=> $trackingNumber, 
        ]); 

       
       Mail:: to($newShipment->email)->send(new RecievedShipment(auth()->user(), $newShipment) );
```

Comment: You have the user_id, query the table to get the email address.

Comment: could you give me an example please?

Comment: Read this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models